# Please any example in cordova for download multiple files sequentially

Tags: file, cordova, download

I need an example to download multiple files, one by one, that is to finalize first one then the next and so on until end all, thanks.

Comment: i am facing the same issue with ionic, i have tried cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer  and use of $q.all() method but error show "File Transfer Error: The request timed out"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin file and file-transfer:

Install via CLI Cordova:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
>
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer

```
fileTransfer.download(
  URLToFile,
  LocalURLDeviceWhereYouStoreTheFiles,
  function(entry) {
    console.log("Success Download");
    // here trigger the next download.
  },
  function(error) {
    
  },
  false,
  {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=="
    }
  });
```

Comment: but this download asyncronized, I need Synchronized